# Netbeans 7.1.2 and 6.7.1, SoapUI both stopped working on OS X Mavericks

Tags: apache, netbeans-7, pycharm, osx-mavericks

Installed the OS X Mavericks last night and Netbeans and SoapUI both doesnt work anymore. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Updating Java JRE fixed Netbeans, other products that are still having issues:

1) SoapUI
2) Apache Directory Studio
3) PyCharm

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Try to install the newest Java JRE. It worked for me

Comment: Thanks, this worked for netbeans, however SoapUI is still in the same situation..

Comment: Maybe update Java SE as well, it works for Adobe Products at least.
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 3):

Downloading [NetBeans 7.4](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=macosx&lang=en&option=php) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Updating Java JRE and downloading NetBeans 7.4 didn’t work for me.

Installation issue : Neatbean 7.4 was unable to install and previous version (7.2 on my computer) was unable to launch.

When i tried to launch Photoshop 5.1, i had a message saying Java SE 6 was missing. Mavericks asked to download it. After installing automatically, Photoshop and Netbeans install was ok.

Also, you can try this link if you can't download automatically :
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573